# Bounding an Unbounded operator and preserving Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, linear-transformations, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose $T:A\mapsto B$ is an unbounded closed linear operator between Hilbert spaces.

Is there a way to construct a bounded closed linear operator $T'$ between $A$ and $B$ satisfying
$$
Ker(T)= Ker(T')?
$$

Comment: Okay. If $T$ is closed, what do you know about $\ker T$?

Comment: Nothing really, T is simply an evaluation map of a certain stochastic integral $H \mapsto \int_0^THdX_t$.  The issue is that I cannot divide by $X_T$ since this quantity may be zero with positive probability.... (So I am trying to approach the problem abstractly).

Comment: The fact that $T$ is a closed linear operator tells you something about $\ker T$. Looking at it from the end you want to reach, if $L$ is a continuous linear operator, then $\ker L$ is closed. So such a $T'$ as you want can only exist if $\ker T$ is closed. Can you deduce that from the premises?

Comment: Yes, this will indeed hold for me

Comment: This holds for every closed linear operator. Now, in your question, you don't require any further connection between $T$ and $T'$ beyond them having the same kernel. Then the question is whether there exists a continuous linear injection $(\ker T)^{\perp} \to B$. If you want further connections between $T$ and $T'$, which?

Comment: No that's alright I need nothing but exactly preserve the Kernel (the rest is unimportant for me).